# Functional HTML tables (sorting, filtering, moving and toggling columns)

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table, filtering

I'm looking for a All-in-one solution for HTML table management. What I'd like to accomplish is to enable user a simple table management which would offer sorting by columns, filtering data (per column or per globally per table), moving columns (changing their order) and toggling columns visibility.

Basically an alternative to ExtJS's feature, which can be seen on this url http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/grid/live-search-grid.html . I wouldn't like to use ExtJS for other reasons, but this they have figured out.

I've searched for existing solutions but couldn't find All-in-one and I wouldn't like to overly complicate my app.

Comment: jquery datatables does about everything tables/grids need to, but no matter what you use, do expect some elbow grease in customizing and connecting the features to your data.

Comment: We've used jqGrid extensively. The latest version requires a commercial license, however. Also, these kinds of questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, and this question is likely to get closed. See [What topics can I ask about?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Well, I'll take a look at both of these. If it gets closed thanks for quick responses :)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a question geared more toward personal preference, however I would recommend [dataTables](https://datatables.net/). It is a very robust JQuery based HTML table  library. It has the majority of the features found in ExtJS and provides easily implemented interactivity.

Comment: if starting out, make sure to use the new version (1.1+). it's better, but can be a pain if used to the old one....

Comment: `datatables.net` is awesome ! I get table rows sort+filter working just after 10 minute coding to update my html view